# In FIX protocol, how to identify if the trade being submitted to foreign country?

Tags: trading, fix

In FIX protocol, how to identify if the trade being submitted to foreign country ?

Answer (score 1):

You should check the API documentation of your counter-party. They might add a custom field to indicate this.